# What's the difference in adding a handler to a child process in Node.js: cp.on('event') vs. cp.stdout('event')

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, child-process

It seems there are two ways for attaching event handlers to a [child processes](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) in Node, one of them is using `cp.stdin.on`, `cp.stdout.on` and `cp.stderr.on`. Another one is adding directly to the child process `cp.on`. What's the difference?

```
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});


ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the event source and what events it offers. `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are streams (`stdin` is a [Writeable stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable), the other two are [Readable streams](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable)). The process is a [ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process). So while the streams have events related to their being streams (for instance, the `data` event on a Readble stream), the child process has events related to it being a child process, such as `exit`.

Comment: `stdout` is basically `console.log`